# I've been trying to display the uploaded image in the browser but nothing display because nothing has found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been trying to display the uploaded image in the browser but nothing display because nothing has found.

My code is written in php and using laravel 5.5 framework, and this are the configuration

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver'     => 'local',
            'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url'        => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

The way I store in the controller is this way

```
$path = $request->file('image');
if (! is_null($path)) {
  $path = $path->store('public/blog');
}
```

Which has no problem,

and the way I call in the blade template is in this way:

```
<a href="{{ route('single.post', $blog->slug) }}">
    <img src="{{ asset("storage/app/public/{$blog->image}") }}">
</a>
```

I already, run this in the terminal `php artisan storage:link` but nothing displayed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove "/app/public" from the path, as you have already run the storage:link command which will create a shortcut link in public folder to the storage folder.